# Firestore Trigger Python Cloud Functions (gen2) - takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed the **firestore trigger function *on_document_created*** as per the example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.firestore_fn#functions

```
@on_document_created(document="test/{testId}")
def example(event: Event[DocumentSnapshot]):
  print("Hello World")
  pass
```

To deploy it I used this command:

```
gcloud functions deploy example --gen2 --trigger-event-filters=type=google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created --trigger-event-filters=database='(default)' --trigger-event-filters-path-pattern=document='' --project test-project --runtime python311 --memory 512 --region europe-west3 --env-vars-file prod.yml
```

Whenever a document is created on firestore the function is correctly called but I get the following error in the logs:

```
TypeError: example() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Can you please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're following the **Firebase** documentation, you should use the **Firebase** CLI to deploy to Cloud Functions. That CLI (unlike `gcloud`) adds the additional information that Google Cloud needs.

For more on this, see the **Firebase** documentation on [deploying Cloud Functions with `firebase deploy`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment).